# Angular Password Strength Extension Color does not work

Tags: angular

I use the extension `@angular-material-extensions/password-strength` and literally just copied the showcase example from here https://angular-material-extensions.github.io/password-strength/home

Somehow the color primary does never appear. Just the blue and the red color appear. I also had to add a

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
 }
```

to fix a error with the color `Expression has changed after it was checked...`

The color does change to something like pink and when it's 100% checked just blue, but I want it to be green of course.

My component.html:

```
    <tr>
      <td>
          <mat-card-subtitle>
              <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="showDetails" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">Show Password Requirements</mat-slide-toggle>
            </mat-card-subtitle>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width" [color]="passwordComponent.color">
          <mat-pass-toggle-visibility #toggle matSuffix></mat-pass-toggle-visibility>
          <input matInput [type]="toggle.type" required placeholder="Password" #password formControlName="password"
            type="password" />
            <mat-hint align="end" aria-live="polite">
                {{password.value.length}} / 25
              </mat-hint>
          <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.password" class="form__error">{{ formErrors.password }} </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-password-strength #passwordComponent min="4" [password]="password.value">
      </mat-password-strength>

      <mat-password-strength-info
        *ngIf="showDetails"
        [passwordComponent]="passwordComponent">
      </mat-password-strength-info>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput required placeholder="Password Confirmation" compare="password"
            name="passwordConfirmation" formControlName="passwordConfirmation" type="password" />
          <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.passwordConfirmation" class="form__error">
            {{ formErrors.passwordConfirmation }} </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Edit: I also found out that `<mat-form-field>` ignores it if I add the option `floatLabel="always"` because the auto function does not work itself for this field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is something related with the theme you have.

To be more precise `.mat-progress-bar-fill::after` what should look for: 
Something like this should work for you:

```
mat-password-strength .mat-progress-bar-fill::after{
    background-color: #4caf50;
}
```

**Check the live example here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-password-stack-55569467?file=styles.css

Comment: Poorly it does not work for me. But it's a good hint with the theme. I can't remember to have activated any custom theme. Where can I find or check it, if there is a theme activated?

Comment: You should have something like: `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` in your styles. (in my example: `styles.css`). Can you make an example of your problem in stackblitz?

Comment: I found it but it's the standard theme `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');` Without it, it looks like nothing so...

Comment: Ok i understood what u meant. I changed it to `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` and now the progress bar has the colors red, yellow and again purple, not green even if the css. Strange...

Comment: If the green doesn't appear it's because your class it's declared before than the import in the css, you have to move it after or change it to: `mat-password-strength .mat-progress-bar-fill::after` , going to update the answer

Comment: My fault was that I not looked right and thought you put the css stuff in the component css not in the global `styles.css`

Comment: Is there any possibility to also let the frame of the input field appear in that color that I selected in the CSS? Because the option is already built-in and it works with the theme colors but not with the CSS colors...

Comment: I updated the example to add this. I  would add a class in the `mat-form-field` (in this example I added the class `mat-password-field`)  to tell them that it gonna be a password  and then add the classes in the style like : `.mat-password-field.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label` and `.mat-password-field.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple` with the new color and background-color. Check it working in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was indeed a problem with my theme (accent color white) I managed to fix it by putting the css in the style.css

```
   .mat-progress-bar.mat-warn .mat-progress-bar-buffer {
    background-color: #ffccbc;
}

.mat-progress-bar.mat-warn .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
    background-color: red !important; 
}

.mat-progress-bar.mat-accent .mat-progress-bar-buffer {
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow !important; 
}

.mat-progress-bar.mat-accent .mat-progress-bar-fill::after{
    background-color: yellow !important; 
}

.mat-progress-bar.mat-primary .mat-progress-bar-buffer {
    background-color: lightgreen !important; 
}

.mat-progress-bar.mat-primary .mat-progress-bar-fill::after{
    background-color: green !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin adjusts the colors based on the .mat-warn, .mat-accent and primary colors of your theme. That is for weak, medium and strong password respectively.

For overwriting your theme's colors for the various thresholds, add to your component's styles the following:

```
      mat-password-strength
        .mat-progress-bar.mat-warn
        .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
        background-color: #f44336;
      }
      mat-password-strength
        .mat-progress-bar.mat-accent
        .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
        background-color: #039be5;
      }
      mat-password-strength .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
        background-color: #64dd17;
      }
```